# Angular directive is showing in wrong place

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngtable

I'm very new at Angular and I'm doing an app where I use ngTable:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngTable"]).controller('mainController', function($scope, NgTableParams) {
    $scope.data = [
        {
            a : "3",
            b : "test" 
        },
        {
            a : "3",
            b : "test" 
        },
        {
            a : "3",
            b : "test" 
        }
    ];
    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: $scope.data});
});
app.directive('appInfo', function() { 
    return { 
        restrict: 'E', 
        scope: { 
            info: '=infoData' 
        }, 
        template:
        "   <tr> " +
        "       <td filter=\"{ a: 'text'}\" sortable=\"'a'\">{{info.a}}</td> " +
        "       <td filter=\"{ b: 'text'}\" sortable=\"'b'\">{{info.b}}</td> " +
        "   </tr> "
    };  
});
```

And here is the html:

```
<div class="main" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <app-info ng-repeat="info in data" info-data="info" />
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that `<app-info>` tag is going to wrong place, inside `div` above the `table` instead of `tbody`. What am I missing?

Whats happening:

```
<div class="main" ...>
    <app-info ... />
    <app-info ... />
    ...
    <table ...
</div>
```

What would be right:

```
<div class="main" ...>
    <table ...>
        <thead>...</thead>
        <tbody>
            <app-info ... />
            <app-info ... />
            ...
        </tbody>
        ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a very common issue where browser have special rendering method for tables, and that don't fit well with angular. It will try to render `<table>`
 by searching `tr`, `td`, `thead`, etc., and just kick out stuff that is not suppose to be here, like `app-info`. It will put unknown element on top of the `table`, and render the rest.

- [Angular table row directive not rendering inside table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030080/angular-table-row-directive-not-rendering-inside-table)
- [Angular Directive table rows issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559271/angular-directive-table-rows-issue)

One way to resolve it is to make your directive an attribute instead of an element:

```
restrict: 'A', 

<tbody>
     <tr app-info ng-repeat="info in data" info-data="info">
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

That way the browser will not remove `app-info`, and angular will have time to render correctly.

You could theorically use `replace : true` in the directive config, but it is deprecated because there is known bugs:

> [replace ([DEPRECATED!], will be removed in next major release - i.e. v2.0)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api)

Answer (score 2):

I think the browser doesn't like having an `app-info` tag inside `tbody`. Before Angular.js can do its magic, browser tries to "fix" your invalid HTML by moving `app-info` outside the table.

You can try changing `restrict: 'A'` and use `<tr app-info...` instead.

However, it's usually not preferred to have table-related tags at the root of templates.