# ng-repeat not working if appending html code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have just made a function that editing html table  elements in angular javascript

```
        $scope.divider = function () {

        var table = document.getElementById("table1");
        var finalpos = "";
        var div = "";
        var divs = "";
        var finals = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tasks.length; i++) {
            divs = "";
            for (var x = 0; x < $scope.columns.length; x++) {
                var tds = table.getElementsByTagName("td")[x].innerHTML;
                var pos1 = tds.search('<div');
                var pos2 = tds.search('</div>');
                if (pos1 == -1 || pos2 == -1) {
                    pos1 = tds.search('<!-- ng');
                    pos2 = tds.search('s -->');
                    div = tds.substr(pos1, pos2 - pos1 + 5);
                    var c1 = tds.substr(0, pos1 - 1);
                    var c2 = tds.substr(pos2 + 5, tds.length);
                } else {
                    div = tds.substr(pos1, pos2 - pos1 + 6);

                    var c1 = tds.substr(0, pos1 - 1);
                    var c2 = tds.substr(pos2 + 6, tds.length);
                }
                finalpos = c1 + c2;
                table.getElementsByTagName("td")[x].innerHTML = finalpos;
                div = ' <td ng-repeat="c in columns"> ' + div + ' </td> ';
                divs = divs.concat(div);
            }
            divs = ' <tr > ' + divs + ' </tr> ';
            console.log(divs);
            finals = finals + divs;

        }
        table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1].outerHTML = finals;
        //console.log($scope.tasks);

    }
```

and after that all angular functions stopped working (ignored).

this html codes after editing :

```
<tr>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <div ng-if="c.columnid == t.transstatus" ng-click="gettask(t)" ng-repeat="t in tasks track  by $index" class="redips-drag ng-scope" valign="top" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">
        <h4 style="height:50px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">asdasdsa</h4>
    </div>
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <div ng-if="c.columnid == t.transstatus" ng-click="gettask(t)" ng-repeat="t in tasks track  by $index" class="redips-drag ng-scope" valign="top" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">
        <h4 style="height:50px;" class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">nfnfhgfh</h4>
    </div>
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <div ng-if="c.columnid == t.transstatus" ng-click="gettask(t)" ng-repeat="t in tasks track  by $index" class="redips-drag ng-scope" valign="top" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">
        <h4 style="height:50px;" class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">zzncvbzxnbn</h4>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <div ng-if="c.columnid == t.transstatus" ng-click="gettask(t)" ng-repeat="t in tasks track  by $index" class="redips-drag ng-scope" valign="top" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">
        <h4 style="height:50px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">zxhkcjhzxkjch</h4>
    </div>
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <div ng-if="c.columnid == t.transstatus" ng-click="gettask(t)" ng-repeat="t in tasks track  by $index" class="redips-drag ng-scope" valign="top" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">
        <h4 style="height:50px;" class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">mdf,n,mdfn</h4>
    </div>
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <div ng-if="c.columnid == t.transstatus" ng-click="gettask(t)" ng-repeat="t in tasks track  by $index" class="redips-drag ng-scope" valign="top" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">
        <h4 style="height:50px;" class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">werew</h4>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngRepeat: t in tasks track  by $index -->
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <div ng-if="c.columnid == t.transstatus" ng-click="gettask(t)" ng-repeat="t in tasks track  by $index" class="redips-drag ng-scope" valign="top" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">
        <h4 style="height:50px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">nbb bv</h4>
    </div>
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <div ng-if="c.columnid == t.transstatus" ng-click="gettask(t)" ng-repeat="t in tasks track  by $index" class="redips-drag ng-scope" valign="top" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">
        <h4 style="height:50px;" class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">وليد 32324</h4>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngRepeat: t in tasks track  by $index -->
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <div ng-if="c.columnid == t.transstatus" ng-click="gettask(t)" ng-repeat="t in tasks track  by $index" class="redips-drag ng-scope" valign="top" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">
        <h4 style="height:50px;" class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">sjkcsjkh</h4>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngRepeat: t in tasks track  by $index -->
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus --
    <!-- end ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus --
    <!-- end ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus --
    <!-- end ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus --
    <!-- end ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus --
    <!-- end ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
</td>
<td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus --
    <!-- end ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <!-- ngIf: c.columnid == t.transstatus -->
    </td>
</tr>
```

and after that ng-click and other functions stopped working.

Comment: I think it's better that define a template that have a columns array in scope. and in it's template use your partial html code.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559271/angular-directive-table-rows-issue and (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030080/angular-table-row-directive-not-rendering-inside-table)[this]

Comment: i recompile the codes but ng-repeat in every '<td'> run so every line is duplicates